# Excel 2010 - calculating time lapsed between 2 dates & times where it is over 31 days

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to find out the time lapsed, Days, Hours & Mins, between 2 days and times?

**Date Opened:** Cell J1 08/08/2012  09:00:02

**Date Resolved:** Cell L1 10/10/2012  07:30:00

I have tried the Following:

```
=INT(L1-J1) &" days "&INT(MOD(L1-J1,1)*24)&" hours " & ROUND(MOD((L1-J1)*24,1)*60,0)&" minutes"
```

this works and gives the lapsed time of 62 days 22 hours 30 minutes

The problem with this is that produces this as a text result meaning that I cannot Average the results automatically

I then tried:

```
=L1-J1
```

The result of this is good as it allows me to use the results and work out averages & sums

But if the lapsed time is over a month it cannot work this out - so this example gives me the incorrect result of 02:22:29 (DD:HH:MM)

What i am looking for is a formula / function that will provide me with the time lapsed in Days/ hours/ mins that correctly shows the number of days even if more than 1 month and that i am able to use the results

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a formatting issue. The format of DD:HH:MM is treating the result as a date (2-Mar-1900 22:29)

Unfortunately I don't think there is a built in format which will give total number of days

You can get the text you want by using formula `=INT(L1-J1)&":"&TEXT(L1-J1,"HH:MM")`but this will be a text value rather than a numerical value

Comment: Maybe - I have used the second example above where lapsed time is under 1 month and it works great formatted as advised dd:hh:mm treating it as time lapsed not as a date 

I have read a number of other threads and a lot of people have said that the dd format only totals the number of days up to, but not greater than a month (31days)

one of them suggested using the square brackets [] to get around this but i cannot make it work?

Comment: yes because then the dd part of the date is the correct number of days

Answer (score 0):

Formatting it to [h]:mm:ss would give you the number of hours. Does that help in anyway?

Comment: Yes and no :) 

I could do with it working out the number of days automatically too - although this formatting does provide the correct time lapsed 

Ideally it would be great if [d]:hh:mm would work, but it doesn't

Comment: check if [this](http://www.msofficeforums.com/excel/4467-excel-convert-format-h-mm-ss-decimal.html) helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is something that can't be done in one cell, but would need to be handled in 2 cells. 1 for calculating the average (and can be hidden), and one for the display you are looking for.